# WinAppDriver continuously throws an error as 'Unknown error, Operation timed out'

Tags: visual-studio, ui-automation, desktop-application, vs-unit-testing-framework, winappdriver

I'm trying to automate UI's of an extension installed in **Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise** using WinAppDriver and after all the successful completion of configurations and test scenarios, the WinAppDriver server keeps throwing an error as below.

```
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 169
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Error
Content-Length: 117
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":13,"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131505)"}}
```

Initially my test suit was successfully run but, now it keeps throwing above error.

Also, in the Visual Studio it logs an error as;

> "Message:
>   Test method abc.1234.test threw exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is how my session is created.

```
if (session == null)
{
TestLogger.LogInfo("Session object is null, creating new singleton object");
Connector winAppRun = new Connector();

try
 {

winAppRun.WinAppUrl = configHelper.GetWinAppDriverURL() + configHelper.GetWinAppDriverPort();
winAppRun.ProjectLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AppLocation");

AppiumOptions opt = new AppiumOptions();

opt.AddAdditionalCapability("app", winAppRun.ProjectLocation);
opt.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
**session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(winAppRun.WinAppUrl), opt, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));**
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

If some one can give a solution for my issue, it would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a [desktop driver session](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#when-and-how-to-create-a-desktop-session) and start your Visual Studio using [Process.Start()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8) method.

You can also try to open the Visual Studio window first and then [to attach your driver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#when-and-how-to-attach-to-an-existing-app-window) to the window.